# How to authenticate permanently using Restsharp

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, html-agility-pack, restsharp

I am developing an application that pulls data from web and parses it using HtmlAgilityPack. However, its not that straight-forward, login is required to access the data.

I am using Restsharp to authenticate like this:

```
        //class definitions 
        request = new RestRequest("http://allpoetry.com/login", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("utf8", "%E2%9C%93");
        request.AddParameter("authenticity_token", "Lr+JtLv7TkZrS73u5scRPbWhuUYDaVF7vd6lkKFF3FKYqNKHircT9v5WCT9EkneTJRsKXaA6nf6fiWopDB0INw==");
        request.AddParameter("referer", url);  // url to the page I want to go
        request.AddParameter("user[name]", "username");
        request.AddParameter("user[password]", "password");
        request.AddParameter("commit", "Log in");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        response = client.Execute(request);
```

This works perfectly but the problem is that I can't Login permanently, i can't make another request using this instance of RestRequest class, it gives the error that I am not logged in. I have found a work-around but it doesn't work with some pages, basically I put the `url` into the `referer` field but I have to make request every time I navigate to another page and this is inconvenient.

How do I login permanently, so I can make new request from the same instance?

Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to send **something** on each request to prove that you have access to the site, whether that be cookies or credentials. Why not just make a method that creates the request, adds the authentication stuff, and returns it to you to further customize the request?

Comment: by doing that it will create new `request` class everytime I call the method and I am currently doing that, I want to make only a single instance of `RestRequest` class and use that instance to further request data.

Comment: You *should* be creating a new instance of `RestRequest` for every request.

Comment: hmm...I think you are right, i did a little research and found out that in order to continue getting data after the request, cookies should be added in the request. Do you know how I can do that?

Answer (score 3):

After some research, I found that the answer is cookies. Each time a request is made, the response has cookies. 
I used the cookies like this.

After `response = client.Execute(request)`I added this:

```
        request.Resource = url;
        request.Method = Method.GET;
        foreach (var cookie in response.Cookies)
        {
            request.AddCookie(cookie.Name , cookie.Value);  //this adds every cookie in the previous response.
        }
        response = client.Execute(request);
       //use the response as required
```

This doesn't create a new instance but uses the same `request` to make further requests and I am logged in through it all.

Thank you everyone for your help!